# How to input variable in FTP

Tags: linux

I need help for the code below:

```
cd /logs
A=$(ls -rt | tail -n3)
echo $A
{ 
Ftp commands starts now
.
.
prompt
bin
mput $A
.
.
}
```

Now `echo $A` gives three log files, but mput is taking only one file as input. I want to input 3 files to mput.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `for` loop to do so, as shown below.

```
for A in `ls -rt | tail -n3`; do
    .
    .
    .
    mput $A
    .
    .
done
```